# Delphi Graphics32 how to draw a line with the mouse on a layer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, graphics32

Can anybody help me convert this great method of dynamically drawing a line [(Photoshop style drawing line with delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497710/how-to-draw-a-line-using-mouse-drag) to Graphics32?

I mean, I want to have a ImgView, add a new layer to it, then perform these methods on the layer instead of the form's canvas.

So I assume, my code should look like this:

```
 private
    FStartPoint, FEndPoint: TPoint;
    FDrawingLine: boolean;
    bm32: TBitmap32;
```

...

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bm32 := TBitmap32.Create;
  FDrawingLine := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ImgView do
  begin
    Selection := nil;
    RBLayer := nil;
    Layers.Clear;
    Scale := 1;
    Bitmap.SetSize(800, 600);
    Bitmap.Clear(clWhite32);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  B : TBitmapLayer;
  P: TPoint;
  W, H: Single;
begin
        B := TBitmapLayer.Create(ImgView.Layers);
        with B do
        try
          Bitmap.DrawMode := dmBlend;
          with ImgView.Bitmap do Location := GR32.FloatRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
          Scaled := True;
          OnMouseDown := LayerMouseDown;
          OnMouseUp := LayerMouseUp;
          OnMouseMove := LayerMouseMove;
          OnPaint := LayerOnPaint;
        except
          Free;
          raise;
        end;
end;
```

I assume this code because those are the events used in the regular canvas drawing method from the link, but the rest of the methods do not work like they should

```
procedure TForm1.AddLineToLayer;
begin
  bm32.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
  bm32.Canvas.LineTo(FEndPoint.X, FEndPoint.Y);
end;

procedure TForm1.SwapBuffers32;
begin
  BitBlt(imgView.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight,bm32.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TForm1.SwapBuffers;
begin
  BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight,
    bm.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;


procedure TForm1.LayerMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FStartPoint := Point(X, Y);
  FDrawingLine := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.LayerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDrawingLine := false;
  FEndPoint := Point(X, Y);
  AddLineToLayer;
  SwapBuffers;
end;

procedure TForm1.LayerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDrawingLine then
  begin
    SwapBuffers;
    ImgView.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
    ImgView.Canvas.LineTo(X, Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.LayerOnPaint(Sender: TObject; Buffer: TBitmap32);
begin
  SwapBuffers;
end;
```

So it does not work. Nothing happens.
Can anybody assist me in making this work like in the normal canvas drawing?
I want to make this happen for just one layer, the layer I create with Button1Click...
(ImgView is a ImgView32 control placed on the form, and there is also a button on the form)

the result looks like this (with error saying that Canvas does not allow drawing)
[image]
First time the error appears onButtonClick, then after I Ok it, I start drawing, it does not erase the moving lines (just like in the image above), then onMouseUp the Canvas error appears again.

What am I doing wrong?

If I use SwapBuffers32, nothing gets drawn , and canvas errors keep showing up.

**EDIT**:
I made a few changes just to try making it work after Tom Brunberg's suggestions and I ended up with this code:

```
 private
    FStartPoint, FEndPoint: TPoint;
    FDrawingLine: boolean;
    bm32: TBitmap32;
    B : TBitmapLayer;
    FSelection: TPositionedLayer;
  public
    procedure AddLineToLayer;
    procedure SwapBuffers32;
    procedure LayerMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure LayerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure LayerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;X, Y: Integer);
    procedure LayerOnPaint(Sender: TObject; Buffer: TBitmap32);
    procedure SetSelection(Value: TPositionedLayer);
    property Selection: TPositionedLayer read FSelection write SetSelection;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TPoint;
  W, H: Single;
begin
   bm32 := TBitmap32.Create;
   bm32.SetSize(800,600);
      with ImgView do
        begin
          Selection := nil;
          Layers.Clear;
          Scale := 1;
          Bitmap.SetSize(800, 600);
          Bitmap.Clear(clWhite32);
        end;

        B := TBitmapLayer.Create(ImgView.Layers);
        with B do
        try
          Bitmap.DrawMode := dmBlend;
          B.Bitmap.SetSize(800,600);
          with ImgView.Bitmap do Location := GR32.FloatRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
          Scaled := True;
          OnMouseDown := LayerMouseDown;
          OnMouseUp := LayerMouseUp;
          OnMouseMove := LayerMouseMove;
          OnPaint := LayerOnPaint;
        except
          Free;
          raise;
        end;
  FDrawingLine := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.AddLineToLayer;
begin
  bm32.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
  bm32.Canvas.LineTo(FEndPoint.X, FEndPoint.Y);
end;

procedure TForm1.SwapBuffers32;
begin
//  BitBlt(imgView.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight,bm32.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  BitBlt(B.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight,bm32.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;


procedure TForm1.LayerMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FStartPoint := Point(X, Y);
  FDrawingLine := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.LayerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Buttons: TMouseButton;Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDrawingLine := false;
  FEndPoint := Point(X, Y);
  AddLineToLayer;
  SwapBuffers32;
end;

procedure TForm1.LayerMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDrawingLine then
  begin
    SwapBuffers32;
    ImgView.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
    ImgView.Canvas.LineTo(X, Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.LayerOnPaint(Sender: TObject; Buffer: TBitmap32);
begin
  SwapBuffers32;
end;


procedure TForm1.SetSelection(Value: TPositionedLayer);
begin
  if Value <> FSelection then
  begin
    FSelection := Value;
  end;
end;
```

Now, no more Canvas errors, but the mouse-move lines stay drawn... The solution must be in the BitBlt function (swapbuffers32). Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting how this question was downgraded for showing no research effort, or for being not helpfull?!?!?! Really? I wonder who did that... In 2 days this question was viewed 97 times and you still find it not helpfull? Or maybe you can find the answer to this question ANYWHERE on google? Please elaborate your downvote with a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the problem with the failing erasure of unwanted lines, we need to review how Anders Rejbrands solution works.
The in-memory bitmap `bm` is the bitmap to which we store **wanted** lines. The `canvas`of the form acts as a pad where we catch the mouse actions and give feedback to the user. Between `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events (which determine the wanted start point and end point) we receive a lot of `MouseMove` events. For each `MouseMove` we first call `SwapBuffers` which **erases** any rubbish (leftover from previous MouseMove) from the forms canvas. Then we draw the line from the start point to current mouse position. The erasure is done by copying (BitBlt) the content of `bm` to the forms canvas.

Because the erasure of unwanted lines doesn't work, we need to look closer at `bm32` in your code. You create it in FormCreate but you never give it a size! And that is the problem. There's nothing to copy from in `SwapBuffers32`.

Also, because the bitmap doesn't have a size, it doesn't allow drawing. Thus the error message.

The other version of `SwapBuffer` refers to a `bm` variable, which is not shown in any other code, so I can't really comment on that at all.

**Edit after update of users code.**

In FormCreate, after setting size of bm32, add

```
  bm32.Clear(clWhite32); // Add this line
```

and change the following two lines

```
//    with ImgView.Bitmap do Location := GR32.FloatRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    B.Location := GR32.FloatRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
//    Scaled := True;
    Scaled := False;
```

and finally at the end of FormCreate add

```
  SwapBuffers32;
```

In LayerMouseMove replace ImgView with B.BitMap

```
//    ImgView.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
//    ImgView.Canvas.LineTo(X, Y);
    B.Bitmap.Canvas.MoveTo(FStartPoint.X, FStartPoint.Y);
    B.Bitmap.Canvas.LineTo(X, Y);
```

and in SwapBuffers32 replace ClientWidth and ClienHeight with properties of B.Bitmap

```
  BitBlt(B.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, B.Bitmap.Width, B.Bitmap.Height,bm32.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

These changes works for me so that bm32 still collects intended lines. Since the last call of MouseUp is to SwapBuffers, the B layer will get a final copy of those lines. The ImgView.Bitmap is not involved for anything as you wanted to have the drawing on the layer.

**Edit after comments from user...**

There is indeed one more change I did. Sorry for forgetting to mention.

In FormCreate, under `with B...`

```
//    Bitmap.DrawMode := dmBlend;
    Bitmap.DrawMode := dmOpaque;
```

Comment: Good point. So, I removed swapbuffers and replaced it with swapbuffers32 everywhere, after I setSize to the bm32. But now, when I click on the ImgView, the whole imgView32 turns black. If I comment the BitBlt call, then no more Canvas errors and the Canvas stays white, but the lines do not get erased, and the result is identical to the image from the question. So the old lines (while mouse moving) do not get erased... So I guess that is the point where I need another approach. Any idea?

Comment: `bm32.Clear(clWhite32)` after setting size? And you need the BitBlt call for the erasure to work.

Comment: Wow, now that was great. It works now (with the original BitBlt call where destination is ImgView.Canvas). However I am not convinced that the actual drawing happens on the layer or on the ImgView. If I do the BitBlt using Layer's Canvas, then nothing changes, the lines still remain drawn. Later I will try to add other layers to the ImgView to see how my drawingLayer impact the other layers, but I do not think it will be ok... Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1137313 I updated my answer based on your new code.

Comment: I am sorry but after doing your changes, it does not work anymore. No line gets drawn ever... However, if I keep my former BitBlt call (drawing on the ImgView Canvas, then it draws the line (with a lot of flickering this time)

Comment: Like this... drawing on ImgView canvas, when I add a new layer (after drawing) the drawings disappear (even if I add a transparent PNG image). So it is not a solution for me to draw to the canvas of ImgView. I need to draw it ON THE LAYER

Comment: If your code works, please paste the entire test unit here. You probably forgot to mention some other change you have made

Comment: There must be something wrong with the usage of BitBlt, because, I did the following: I added to the form an Image32, then in SwapBuffers32 I added these lines: `Image321.Bitmap.Assign(bm32);` and then `B.Bitmap.Assign(bm32);`. And this way, my lines appear like they should, and also this way, I can add other layers to the ImgView. Can you make your approach (using BitBlt), work? Please do that in a new answer and I will accept it. (Paste your unit that works)

Comment: @user Sorry, but there was indeed one more change I did. Edited my answer. Assigning bm32 to B.Bitmap works also, but copies all properties, not just the pixel data. You may not always want that. If the code doesn't work as with this added change I can post the whole unit.

Comment: Thank you. Great solution. Please check out my related question at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534892/delphi-graphics32-transparent-layer-draw-line because I cant seem to be able to make this layer transparent so you might help with that too. I accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

In Firemonkey, I did this using a bitmap to draw the line from 2 points.

Basically, before the line begins (on mouse down, event) , you take a screenshot of the area where you want to draw the line.

Then when the mouse is moving you draw a line on the bitmap copy. Each time before the line is drawn on the bitmap, you replace the bitmap with the original screenshot. Might need tinkering with a bit, but seems to work ok. 
In the code below the image is aligned to the client of the area where you wish to draw.

Code....

```
procedure TForm3.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin

  if Button = TmouseButton.mbLeft then
  begin
    startPoint := pointf(X,Y);
    endPoint := StartPoint;
    saveScreen := Image1.MakeScreenshot;
    Image1.Bitmap := saveScreen;
    Panel1.HitTest := false;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);

begin

  if ssLeft in Shift  then
  begin
    EndPoint := pointf(X,y);
    Image1.Bitmap := saveScreen;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene();
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Green;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(StartPoint, endPoint  ,1);
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

 end;

procedure TForm3.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin

   Image1.canvas.beginscene;
   Image1.Bitmap := saveScreen;
   Image1.canvas.endScene;
   //Panel1.HitTest := true;  ignore this for now.
end;
```

I think there might be another way  in fire monkey to achieve a line drawn with the mouse, and that's by dropping a TLine on the form, setting the rotation angle of x,y to 0. When drawing a line create a bounding rectangle from begin, end points, work out the rotation angle of the triangle intersection of the bounding rectangle from begin point (normalised rectangle), and basically change the rotation angle of the TLine to whatever it is. position the line at the start point, then tinker with the length. Thoughts anyway. Might be another method. Sorry for lack of code on this...